# GLenum as property in Objective-C OpenGL

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, textures

i have a problem with OpenGLES on iOS. To render a texture i load it via

```
if (numberOfMipmaps > 0) {
    if (textureData != 0)
        glDeleteTextures(1, &textureData);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glGenTextures(1, &textureData);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureData);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR();

    for (GLint i = 0; i < numberOfMipmaps; i++) {
        unsigned char *data = mipmaps[i].address;

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i, internalFormat, width, height, 0, format, target, data);
        //glGenerateMipmapOES(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        CHECK_GL_ERROR();

        width = MAX(width >> 1, 1);
        height = MAX(height >> 1, 1);
    }
}
```

internalFormat, format and target are syntesized properties which i declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) GLint internalFormat;
@property (nonatomic, assign) GLenum format;
@property (nonatomic, assign) GLenum target;
```

the problem is that it doesn't work this way. i get no compile or runtime error. i only see a white screen, which is an indicator that no data is loaded into the texture memory. i set these three variables in my constructor

```
internalFormat = GL_RGBA;
format = GL_RGBA;
target = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1;
```

the idea behind this is to inherit from my class to provide other texture formats like RGB565.
It used to work if i simply overload the method where i create the GL texture and hardcode the glTexImage2D function

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_565, data);
```

can anyone explain to me why it's not working when i use properties.

EDIT:
just to be clear: the question is why cant i use properties as parameters in the glTexImage2D function?

EDIT 2:
i think i get the problem. GL_RGBA and GL_UNSIGNED... are defines in the opengles header files, therefor the ObjC precompiler pastes the hex codes into the glTexImage2D function call. if i use variables, the precompiler does not change anything and the values are inserted on runtime and THAT does not work.

Comment: Do you want to use GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1 or GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_565 as target? Because as a property you use one value, but in example of glTexImage2D function call you use different value.

Comment: where did you assign them? in `init` method? did you call `[super ini]` in the subclass?

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko: well, both. i want to inherit from the main class. but thats not the point. loading and using a texture works if i don't use properties. i debugged the method and double checked that the properties have the right values.

Comment: Your "edit 2" is on the wrong track. The preprocessor turns those definitions into numeric constants at compile time, either at the call site if you use them directly, or where the property is assigned otherwise. It doesn't look any different to the called function.

Answer (score 0):

The `GLenum` type is just a typdef'd `unsigned int` on iOS. You should be able to use them as "assign" property types as you would any other unsigned int, which appears to be just as you're doing, so something is wrong in your actual assignment/usage of the properties.

---

By the way, you're accessing those synthesized ivars directly in your actual code. If you're using properties, you should probably use e.g. `self.format` or `[self format]` there for clarity, even though it may not be strictly necessary here.

Comment: i did, but that didn't help. and , btw, since my properties are assigned, i think it does not matter which call i use, 'format =' or 'self.format ='

Comment: @user890270 When you use `format = ` instead of `self.format =`, you're using the synthesized instance variable directly, rather than the property accessor. The distinction probably doesn't matter here, because as you say it's assigned anyways, but I'd recommend consistency and using the accessor for clarity in your code. (Updated answer on this point.)

Comment: @user890270: Anyways, you should post the full method where you're setting the values. Are you certain that that method (initializer) is the one being called? Have you set a breakpoint to verify that? If so, have you set a breakpoint to confirm the values are then still what you expect when you're rendering? Something fundamental is not working here.